# gstreamer gst_child_proxy_set C syntax

Tags: c, merge, gstreamer

I am struggling with some gstreamer code in C, which I cannot write. I am asking you to give me simple example of C syntax code of two videotestsrc'es which would be displayed in one window using gst_child_proxy_set -> xpos,ypos. I cannot figure it out because of lack of examples, I'm quite new to Gstreamer but really need to do it this way. I know for some of you it is just a moment to write that and I am trying for couple of days now...
Best regards!

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix \
        sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
        sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
        sink_2::xpos=640 sink_2::ypos=0 \
        sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=360 \
        sink_4::xpos=640 sink_4::ypos=360 \
    ! autovideosink \
videotestsrc pattern="black" \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=1280,height=720 \
    ! mix.sink_0 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.121:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_1 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.122:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_2 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.123:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_3 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.124:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_4 \
```

Comment: You might not find this useful, but I don't think GstChildProxy is the right tool for what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe try setting two different surfaces as video sinks, and put one beside the other.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve what I am trying to do, but I created one liner which works well, and now I need to write same in C to use it for further application. Maybe could you help with "translating" my command line into C?

Comment: Good! I guess you are refering to a `gst-launch` command, aren't you? If so it's a pretty good start and you definitely should paste it in you post. :)

Comment: yep, I am. I stucked with it rly badly. I'll edit top question

Comment: @giant_teapot any ideas now?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you have managed to create a working pipeline with `gst-launch`. As you may now, your Gstreamer pipeline describes the processing your data is going through from its source (your RTSP stream) to a sink (an autovideosink followed by a neat mixer to have your streams side by side).

From now on, to use it in some useful C code you have two options :

- use `gst-parse-launch` (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch) with the pipeline description you've just used. It will build the whole pipeline just like `gst-launch` would have.
- or you could build the pipeline yourself, using GstElement factories, and binding those elements together. This is very tedious and only useful if you need a dynamic pipeline from the beginning.

So my advice would be to use something like :

```
const char *pipeline_desc = "videomixer name=mix "
    "sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0 "
    "sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 "
    "sink_2::xpos=640 sink_2::ypos=0 "
    /* bla bla... */
    "! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 "
    "! mix.sink_4";


GstElement *pipeline = gst-parse-launch(pipeline_desc, NULL);
```

This plus some event handling, and you should get what you want.

You can find some examples of this and much more in this very good tutorial : http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735

This doc got me out of trouble a few time. :)
Good luck!

---

**EDIT** : just saw you authored [GStreamer multiple videos in one window - C syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120644/gstreamer-multiple-videos-in-one-window-c-syntax) and what you tried there was building the pipeline yourself. While it should work it represents an insane amount of work, is very error prone, and I must confess I never got much out of it myself. :p

`gst-parse-launch` was created for human being such as you and me. :)

Comment: Ye i know your first solution but problem is, I need to build it by myself because of further aplication which will be to stream this four videos as one stream using rtsp-server... I just can't go through creating this pipeline  myself so I'm looking for simple example of creating just two sinkpads with different parameteres so I could use it for my code.
EDIT: I did... and apparently, I failed :D I would gladly use gst-parse-launch and probably could do it for multiple videos, but is it possible to sink to rtsp your way?

Comment: I get you, but udp does not provide rtsp address, it just let you listen on specified port. Or maybe can I link rtsp-server somehow?

Comment: Tried to look into this, but I'm not sure. I've had experience with the client side of the toolkit, no that much with the server side. There is a `GstRTSPServer` (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPServer.html) but no idea how it really works. :(

Comment: So menaged to get to that point so far:) I'm just curious if I could use your way and connect it with gstRTSPServer somehow in code or I stuck in same place I'm here that I can't do it ;P Tell me one more thing, in pipeline_desc, do I need just to copy my one liner into that char?

Comment: Yup. Your pipeline description is all that is after `gst-launch-1.0 -e` (cf. manpage).

Comment: If you're still stuck after a while, go ask the devs on IRC (#gstreamer on freenode). They're very helpful and aware of the state of their own documentation. Ask precisely what you want, be patient, and you should get an anwser.

Comment: Looks like I will never find right solution for this very "motherfck..." question;)

Comment: TBH, that's what I thought back then about this whole thing. But heh, two years after the job's long done and I'm still alive. Good luck, you can beat this! :)

Comment: is it possible so you contact me via mail? I've got few questions.

Comment: Sure. I was wondering how you could be doing no later than yesterday. Hope I'll be able to help you. Send to contact <at> giant-teapot <dot> org

Comment: look your emailbox. Second one is the right one. First got troubled by autocorrect;)